# Why Setup() method and function default() method gives two different results for http.post() in k6

Tags: performance, k6

I want to execute a Perf script with a oAuth2 token generation. For that I'm following these 2 approaches,

1. Scenario based approach(`export function setup()`)

So in here I'm creating token inside the export function setup() method as follows

```
export function setup(){
  const clientId = '';
  const clientSecret = '';
  const tokenUrl = 'https://testing123.com/oauth2/token';

  let body = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=" + clientId + "&client_secret=" + clientSecret;
  var res = http.post(tokenUrl, body, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } });
  var result = JSON.parse(res.body);
  console.log("res: "+res)
  console.log("result: "+ res.body )
  var token = result.access_token;
  return token;
}
```

The output for result is something like this

```
INFO[0004] res: [object Object]                          source=console
INFO[0004] result: null                                  source=console
```

2. "`export default function()`" based approach

when I do the same token generation inside export function default() method as a separate method to create token

```
//token generation
function getAccessToken() {
    const clientId = '';
    const clientSecret = '';
    const tokenUrl = 'https://testing123.com/oauth2/token';

    let body = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=" + clientId + "&client_secret=" + clientSecret;
    var res = http.post(tokenUrl, body, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } });
    var result = JSON.parse(res.body);
    console.log("res: "+res)
    console.log("result: "+ res.body )
    var token = result.access_token;
    return token;
}


export default function () {
    const token = getAccessToken();

    getBuckets(token);
    getBucketExport(token)
    postBucketSummary(token);
}


export function getBuckets(token) {
    console.log("Executing getItems ")
    const apiUrl = 'https://bucket.com/bucket_vendor=403741,2236';

    const headers = {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        Connection: `keep-alive`
    };
    const response = http.get(apiUrl, { headers },{
        tags: { custom_tag: 'getItems' },
      });
    console.log(`Response status: ${response.status}`);
    requestTrend1.add(response.timings.duration)
    sleep(1);
}
```

the output for result is something like this,

```
INFO[0003] res: [object Object]                          source=console
INFO[0003] result: {"access_token":"GENERATED TOKEN","expires_in":7200,"token_type":"Bearer"}  source=console
```

Why they act differently in this time? I want access_token to be generated in the first approach. Because I want to run the tests based on the scenarios.

```
Version: k6.exe v0.48.0 (commit/47c0a26798, go1.21.5, windows/amd64)
OS: Windows
```

Edit: This is the message I receive when I add following code after receiving post output in the **first** scenario, This is

```
var res = http.post(tokenUrl, body, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } });
console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
```

[image]

Comment: What is `res.status` of each response?

Comment: @knittl 200 in both the occasions

Comment: Then it should contain the same content. Any typos? What happens if you change your setup to `return getAccessToken()`?

Comment: @knittl still gets `INFO[0003] res: [object Object]                          source=console
INFO[0003] result: null                                  source=console' `

Not sure why, there are no typos as well. Cannot even think of any other alternative method to implement oAuth2 with Scnearios

Comment: @knittl Can you recheck, I have edited my question with more information. Even though I receive 200, body is null. Is this due to some blockage when running token generation inside setup() method

Comment: I don't see anyhting wrong. It shouldn't matter if you call the method (`getAccessToken()`) from the setup or from the default method.

Comment: @knittl Yeah strange issue, not sure what's wrong. BTW in the edit I have added mistakenly i got that message(image) in the second scenario, but it happened in first scenario.